# call C function with variable arguments count

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

How can I rewrite the following block of code?  I need to extract some arguments via function token() and then call printf with those arguments. Number of arguments isn't known.

```
char *S[32]; int i=0;
while (t) {
    char *s=token(&t, lineno, 0);
    assert(i<sizeof(S)/sizeof(S[0]));
    S[i++]=s;
}
printf(f, S[0], S[1], S[2], S[3], S[4], S[5], S[6], S[7], S[8], S[9],
     S[10], S[11], S[12], S[13], S[14], S[15], S[16], S[17], S[18], S[19],
     S[20], S[21], S[22], S[23], S[24], S[25], S[26], S[27], S[28], S[29],
     S[30], S[31]);
```

Comment: your tag `va_arg` for this question is the answer.

Comment: `Number of arguments isn't known.` loop after, i value.

Comment: There's really nothing you can do, as you can't dynamically add arguments to a function call runtime.

Comment: Also, depending on situation you might have a big security problem in that `printf` statement, if the format string can be entered by a user. What if the user puts in more formating specifications than the max number of arguments? That will cause undefined behavior as `printf` tries to fetch non-existing arguments.

Comment: Do you have to assume any format is `f`?

Comment: f can contain any formats, but program replaces all format specifiers to 's' (%<ANYTHING>d --> %s). One exception is %<ANYTHING>s -- this format is retained as is. Program can count number of format specifiers -- so there a no security hole.

Comment: I should repeat with `i` it?

Comment: e.g)`for(j=0;j<i;++j)printf(f, s[j]);`

Comment: if your program can control f, just chop it up into single string formats and use the loop solution of BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use vprintf :
[vprintf reference on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vprintf/)

Comment: But how can i construct arguments list in that case?  va_arg() macro is not lvalue...
token() function reads arguments (all are strings) from file.

Comment: Maybe you should write an auxilary function to print the variables arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`array[] = { aPointer,aPointer,...,NULL}`

Answer (score 0):

Are these arguments to be taken in from the commandline?  If so, then utilise `argc` and `argv`: `main (int argc, char *argv[])` and pass them into a function to parse them as needed, removes the need for tokenisation and will handle multiple variable arguments :)

**Addendum:**
For reading arguments in from file:

I have a couple of C answers for you, dependant on how you wish to implement them, the second example code just does a straight read and dump, the first reads and then tokenises to dump 9you could utilise them differently this is just a quick demo to show how to tokenise args from a file:):

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    int sizerValue = 1024;
    char s1[sizerValue],*p;
    f = fopen("testFile.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(s1, sizerValue, f))
    {
    while (fgets(s1, sizerValue, f))
    {
        p=strtok(s1, ";n");
        do
        {
             printf ("%sn",p);
        }
        while(p=strtok(NULL,";n"));
        }
    }
return 0;
}       

#include <stdio.h>
#define BLOCK   1024

int main() {
    FILE *f=fopen("TestFile.txt","r");
    int size;
    char buffer[BLOCK];
    while((size=fread(buffer,BLOCK,sizeof(char),f)>0)
            fwrite(buffer,size,sizeof(char),stdout);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```